# Failure while compiling apt - Yocto

Tags: debian, yocto, debian-based

I am trying to build a linux image from yocto. To make it debian based, I am using https://github.com/meta-debian/meta-debian and also following there instructions. The only major thing that I have added is the following lines in my build/conf/local.conf file:

```
IMAGE_FEATURES += " package-management"

IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " apt"
```

But, apt fails to compile with the following error:

```
ERROR: apt-1.2.24-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: apt-1.2.24-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/preempt/debian-preempt/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-deby-linux/apt/1.2.24-r0/temp/log.do_compile.110040)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/preempt/debian-preempt/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-deby-linux/apt/1.2.24-r0/temp/log.do_compile.110040
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'bit-64', 'x86_64-linux', 'common']
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: make -j 1
| Generating POT file /home/preempt/debian-preempt/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-deby-linux/apt/1.2.24-r0/build/po/apt.pot
| mv: cannot stat '/home/preempt/debian-preempt/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-deby-linux/apt/1.2.24-r0/build/po/domains/apt/c.pot.tmp': No such file or directory
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| makefile:32: recipe for target '/home/preempt/debian-preempt/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-deby-linux/apt/1.2.24-r0/build/po/apt.pot' failed
| make[2]: *** [/home/preempt/debian-preempt/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-deby-linux/apt/1.2.24-r0/build/po/apt.pot] Error 1
| Makefile:14: recipe for target 'all' failed
| make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
| makefile:18: recipe for target 'all' failed
| make: *** [all] Error 2
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/preempt/debian-preempt/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-deby-linux/apt/1.2.24-r0/temp/log.do_compile.110040)
ERROR: Task (/home/preempt/debian-preempt/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/apt/apt_1.2.24.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 987 tasks of which 986 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/preempt/debian-preempt/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/apt/apt_1.2.24.bb:do_compile
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same error with the same recipe. You can bitbake clean the specific package, and rebuild it. Then rerun your full build.

```
bitbake -b meta/recipes-devtools/apt/apt_1.2.24.bb -c clean -D
bitbake -b meta/recipes-devtools/apt/apt_1.2.24.bb -D
```